# How to get a full URL given a shortened one passed to Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, scraper

I want to traverse some HTML documents with Nokogiri.
After getting the XML object, I want to have the last URL used by Nokogiri that fetched a document to be part of my JSON response.

```
def url = "http://ow.ly/hh8ri"     
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)
...
```

Nokogiri internally redirects it to http://www.mp.rs.gov.br/imprensa/noticias/id30979.html, but I want to have access to it.

I want to know if the "doc" object has access to some URL as attribute or something.
Does someone know a workaround?

By the way, I want the full URL because I'm traversing the HTML to find `<img>` tags and some have relative ones like: "/media/image/image.png", and then I adjust some using:

```
URI.join(url, relative_link_url).to_s
```

The image URL should be:

```
http://www.mp.rs.gov.br/media/imprensa/2013/01/30979_260_260__trytr.jpg
```

Instead of:

```
http://ow.ly/hh8ri/media/imprensa/2013/01/30979_260_260__trytr.jpg
```

EDIT: IDEA

```
class Scraper < Nokogiri::HTML::Document
  attr_accessor :url

  class << self

    def new(url)
        html = open(url, ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
        self.parse(html).tap do |d|
            url = URI.parse(url)
            response = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
            head = response.start do |r|
              r.head url.path
            end 
            d.url = head['location']
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nokogiri knows nothing about URLs, only a string of XML or HTML content, or a file handle. OpenURI returns a StringIO, which imitates an IO stream, allowing Nokogiri to get at the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Mechanize. The URLs will always be converted to absolute:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://ow.ly/hh8ri'
page.images.map{|i| i.url.to_s}
#=> ["http://www.mp.rs.gov.br/images/imprensa/barra_area.gif", "http://www.mp.rs.gov.br/media/imprensa/2013/01/30979_260_260__trytr.jpg"]
```

Comment: Nice, it works! Although it works for absolute images, Mechanize is too limited for other thinks for my scraper with xpath and custom things. I'm not sure if I use Mechanize and Nokogiri together. But nice answer. I will check Mechanize core code to see if I can learn something from there. Thanks!

Comment: Mechanize and nokogiri go together better than you know. For example, mechanize uses nokogiri for a parser and the same developers maintain both libraries.

Comment: hmmm. nice. you are right, maybe I will use mechanize then. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because your example is using OpenURI, that's the code to ask, not Nokogiri. Nokogiri has NO idea where the content came from.

OpenURI can tell you easily:

```
require 'open-uri'

starting_url = 'http://www.example.com'
final_uri = nil

puts "Starting URL: #{ starting_url }"

io = open(starting_url) { |io| final_uri = io.base_uri }
doc = io.read

puts "Final URL: #{ final_uri.to_s }"
```

Which outputs:

```
Starting URL: http://www.example.com
Final URL: http://www.iana.org/domains/example
```

`base_uri` is documented in the [OpenURI::Meta](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/Meta.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue recently. What I did was to create a class that inherits from `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`, and then just override the`new` class method to parse the document, then save the url in an instance variable with an accessor:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class Webpage < Nokogiri::HTML::Document
  attr_accessor :url

  class << self

    def new(url)
      html = open(url)
      self.parse(html).tap do |d|
        d.url = url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can just create a new `Webpage`, and it will have access to all the normal methods you would have with a `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`:

```
w = Webpage.new("http://www.google.com")
w.url
#=> "http://www.google.com"
w.at_css('title')
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4952f78 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4952cb2 "Google">]>]
```

If you have some relative url that you got from an image tag, you can then make it absolute by passing the return value of the `url` accessor to `URI.join`:

```
relative_link_url = "/media/image/image.png"
=> "/media/image/image.png"
URI.join(w.url, relative_link_url).to_s
=> "http://www.google.com/media/image/image.png"
```

Hope that helps.

p.s. the title of this question is quite misleading. Something more along the lines of "Accessing URL of Nokogiri HTML document" would be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried your code but unfortunately it still returns the shortened url instead of the full.

Comment: You mean it returns the relative url when you get the `src` of an `img` tag? It won't change that. All it does is give you access to the root url, which you can then join to get the full url of any link in the doc.

Comment: I added an example. See if that makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, unless the "w.url" is a shortened link like "bit.ly/234"

Comment: I don't understand. You mean that you want to create a document with a shortened link? That won't work. You can't generate a URI from a relative url, without any other information about the root. You have to have an absolute url somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand what are you understand too. But check out a solution based on this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5872658/255932) and your code. It works, but the downside is that it does one request more..