# How can I check if two URLs redirect to the same address (Rails 4.1.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In working on my Rails app, I have learned that "facebook.com/1234" AND "facebook.com/4321" could both potentially lead to "facebook.com/joe.bloggs". Bottom line, two numeric ids can redirect to the same user. I am collecting one numeric id using the authentication on my mobile app, but the authentication that occurs on my website dispenses yet another numeric id that points to the user. If I input either number after "facebook.com/", the browser will redirect it to "facebook.com/joe.bloggs" (example of course).

How can I see if these two numeric ids point to the same user in my Rails app?

Comment: This is answered well at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872210/get-redirect-of-a-url-in-ruby