# Ruby detect redirections without downloading the page

Tags: ruby, http-status-code-302

Is there a way to detect a redirection in Ruby ?

I just want to know if the link gets redirected, without downloading a page and checking for exceptions.

The faster it is, the better.

Comment: does this help [get-redirect-of-a-url-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872210/get-redirect-of-a-url-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-head

```
response = nil
Net::HTTP.start('some.www.server', 80) {|http|
  response = http.head('/index.html')
}
```

`head` call gets just only the header and you can check the response code to detect the redirection.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am using it correctly or not but I keep getting socket error exceptions on most websites ( no matter what socket I input )